# Can I send an automated email address verification (from address management) to the contact email when a contact record is created in SFDC

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can I send an automated email address verification (from address management) to the contact email when a contact record is created in SFDC?

I know we can do this manually through various ways:

1. Importing email addresses from a DE
2. Entering max 20 email addresses
3. Entering one by one email address

But is there any automated way where/ when a contact record is created in Salesforce it auto triggers the email verification to that email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? *From Address Management* is meant to ensure you are allowed to use the email address as a sender address. Adding all your contacts there, allowing you to send emails which appear to be sent by them, is a rather strange use case.

Also, adding email addresses to *From Address Management* has very limited effect.

The only verification happening here, is ensuring you have ownership of the specific email address, to prevent you from sending emails from Marc Benioff’s email address. This verification does not provide any authentication (SPF/DKIM) and will hence not guarantee your email does not trigger the spam filter on the receiving end. This is why I never really use this feature, but rely only on domains which are authenticated as either SAP or Private Domain.

Comment: you got a good question however my use case is that when a certain indicator on a contact is triggered I want to get that contact's email id added into From Address management and send them authentication email to accept to send email on their behalf but as them.
I can very well understand about the functionality so don't want to authenticate a complete domain instead email id.
Note: If I don't authenticate an email id then it will use the Fallback Id to send as from in the email (pls correct me if I'm missing anything) which I don't want so looking for options to verify email address.

Comment: @JimmyVaswani - I think this might get you in trouble, as you will have your IP address send emails from A LOT of unauthenticated domains, which I really think is a bad practice. Also, you might run into a limitation (don't know if there is one) on how many unique email addresses you can verify

Comment: ok thank you @Lukas Lunow.