# API for querying the "From Address Management" , is it possible to add email filter?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, marketingcloudapi

We're querying the "From Address Management" records so as give to option to verify the email address accordingly. However this is taking sometimes more longer than expected and the worry part is this table will keep on growing, is it possible to add email filter or any other easier way possible to query records which will give us the results more faster.

Currently we're querying the whole table and storing (temp) in our code to navigate through viewing the records but I'm positive there might be a better filter (e.g. querying email address directly will be the ideal).

In past I checked with Salesforce about the filter for email address but they said they don't have it and might not have it for a while. But not sure if anything changed.

Comment: As I also mentioned to you in [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404274/can-i-send-an-automated-email-address-verification-from-address-management-to) it is a really bad idea to rely on verified email addresses in your "from address management". You are putting your deliverability at risk by sending from (potentially) a large number of unauthenticated domains.

Comment: Okay, thanks Lukas.